# Using Accuweather API in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have registered for an accuweather developer account and have an apikey.
How do I make a call to the accuweather api in swift and how do I interpret the result, that I got back?

```
let citySearchURL = "https://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=my_api_key&q=my_location_query"     
let url : URL = URL(string: citySearchURL)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data : Data?, response : URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
                    print(json)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

This is my current piece of code. It gives me no output to the console, which means that the JSON Serialization didn't work properly. What did I do wrong?
Below is the content of data, response and error:

`data:936 bytes

response:<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000036520>` Here follows some more json, but stackoverflow doesn't recognize it as code/quotes...

Link to the api reference: [Accuweather API](https://developer.accuweather.com/accuweather-locations-api/apis/get/locations/v1/cities/search)

Comment: How far does your code get? If `data` is `nil`, print `error`.

Comment: I do receive data, when I print it, the consoles says: 936 bytes

Comment: OK, then what happens? Please don't make this a game of 20 questions. Tells us what is actually happening. If there is any output from printing error, include that in the question.

Comment: @FlorianSchweizer try with `let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print(responseString)`

Answer (score 2):

`data:936 bytes` mean that you received API response of `936` bytes, so there no issue.

The issue is you can not parse that `data` to object, in your JSONSerialization statement you added `[String:Any]` as optional type but response is not of this type, thats way the print statement not getting execute.

```
    let citySearchURL = "https://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=my_api_key&q=my_location_query"     
    let url : URL = URL(string: citySearchURL)!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data : Data?, response : URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [Any]{
                    print(json)
                }
           } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Now how do I work with the data this returns?
It is an array of type Any, so I can't directly access an "attribute"

Comment: @FlorianSchweizer i think you are bit new to Swift development, so just go through it, and search "swift 4 Json parsing" you'll got lots of result related to it. one of them is : https://grokswift.com/json-swift-4/